# Hiking around Hyderabad, India?

Tags: india, hiking, hyderabad

I'm looking for an opportunity to do a hike around the city of Hyderabad, India. The hike should lead to a summit, lake, mountain hut or something similar, ie. there should be a clear goal that I can reach. The hike should be doable in 1 day and it should be easily reachable from Hyderabad. Additionally, I should be able to do it alone, ie. no guide or any other things like that should be needed.

Comment: For hiking and other outdoor activities, see also [Outdoors.SE].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Golkonda Fort**

If you're interested in looking at a fort, then I can suggest you [Golkonda Fort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golkonda). It is almost 11 Km from city center, but the distance will of course depend on the area, you're staying in. The fort had a vault which stored world famous **[Kohinoor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohinoor)** and **[Hope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hope_diamond)** diamonds once.

The fort itself is an impressive structure and quite huge, giving you a lot of opportunities to explore around, photograph the place and around. The fort overlooks the city, so you will get vantage poitns for having a look at the city.

**Hussain Sagar Lake**

The man made [lake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hussain_Sagar) has a lot of structures and attractions around it. Most notably being the Buddha statue in the middle of the lake. You can enjoy a clear evening around the lake, with sunset presenting beautiful scene.

Apart from these, you can check the route and attractions for some heritage walks inside the city, which cover monuments inside the city. The official state tourism department website lists 4 routes. You can check [this site](http://aptdc.in/heritage_walks/index.php), to explore more about the route and attractions.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds not too bad, but I'm more interested in a little bit more serious hiking.

Comment: In that case, you can find hiking groups in Hyderabad and maybe contact them for the tours they have, jsut to have a n idea about the route. Or maybe check their website/email them for more information hiking.meetup.com/cities/in/hyderabad/